# Validating XML layout for DockPanel

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dockpanel-suite

I got some errors while loading corrupted xml layouts for DockPanel, so I'm trying to code a function to assure that the xml layout is correct before loading it with `LoadFromXml`. Is there any XSD file for validate the XML saved from DockPanel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is none so far. If you can create one and share with us, we can integrate it in https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite

Comment: Well, I'll try it, but I'm not proficient on DockPanel, so I don't promise anything :P

Comment: I have a preliminar version, that apparently works on my application. How I can send it to you?

Comment: Please create a GitHub account (if you don't have yet), fork from dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite, in your own fork add this XSD file to a location that you find suitable, and finally send a pull request back.  https://help.github.com/ You can learn about GitHub from here.